# Including a Maven Project as a plugin in another project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, plugins

I'm developing a Maven plugin using Eclipse. I have a Java project for this Maven plugin in Eclipse, as well as another test project to test this plugin, i.e. this test project would thus include the plugin jar generated by the Maven project.

The Maven plugin has been added as a plugin in the pom.xml file of my test project. Consequently, I have to recompile the Maven project into a plugin jar every time I want to test a change I've made to the plugin. I was wondering if there was some way in Eclipse to include the source code of the Maven project in the test project, so that I wouldn't have to recompile the plugin every time I want to test it?

Comment: Use unit and integration tests rather than running the code for real - that way you will not have to actually run a build with the plugin to test it.

Comment: You're probably right...but I was really hoping there was some way I could just use the source code without recompiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to test a plugin in maven is to use [maven-invoker-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/) which helps to create integration tests for it.

The best thing is to take a look into real plugins with working examples like this:

[iterator-maven-plugin](https://github.com/khmarbaise/artifactor-maven-plugin) or other plugins like maven-jar-plugin etc.